# Is it OK to use a transformer as an AC power supply source?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, ac

I work as an IT specialist in company.  The company acquired a used Axis 232D+ surveillance camera.

This camera is special. It requires a 24V AC 1.5A power source ([as specified on p.48 here.](https://www.axis.com/dam/public/e6/fa/19/axis-231d%2B_axis-232d%2B-users-manual-en-US-36793.pdf)) It was not included in the package, so I need some device to give power to the camera. No local vendors have AC power supplies, only DC ones. I have found a transformer in a local store which provides 24V 40W output.

Is it OK to connect such a transformer directly to power a camera? One pair of wires goes to the power supply network 220V and another pair of wires go to the camera.

I looked on the internet, and mostly found explanations of AC to DC power supplies, but not much mention of AC to AC power supplies. I am not an electrical engineer, I am just afraid to break the camera. By the way, sometimes there may be power oscillations in the network, sudden outages and such (I remember from school that transformers may act erratically when power quickly goes up or down.)

Comment: Measure the voltage with a multimeter before connecting it. Just for luck.

Comment: thanks a lot, will measure it once company manager purchases that transformer

Comment: Is the camera type specified for 50 Hz or 60 Hz? What is your local supply frequency?

Comment: My local power supply is 50Hz 220V

Comment: That's exactly how things with AC inputs are meant to be powered. An AC power brick is just a transformer and nothing else. You are just building the power brick yourself instead of buying a power brick. Note that you won't have a plastic box around the transformer to stop you touching the 220V wires, unless you put a plastic box around the transformer to stop you touching the 220V wires.

Answer (score 4):

From your linked manual:

> 19 - 28 VAC, max 25 VA
> 24 - 40 VDC, max 20 W

The transformer is fine. Any 24Vdc is also fine.

Comment: Page 55, "Power" section, for those playing along at home.

Answer (score 3):

That should be fine. 24 V × 1.5 A = 36 W so your 40 W (technically it's 40 VA) should be fine. The voltage regulation and transient suppression will be handled by the camera.

Install the transformer in an insulated enclosure and fit a 1 A fuse in series with the primary live supply.

You need to pay attention to the class of insulation between the primary and secondary windings as this will determine the earthing arrangement required. Edit your question and add a photo if unsure.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, I ask a vendor for 1A fuse (they should have it) and a plastic box as well to insulate camera from possible humid air

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a transformer will work fine. Make sure to mount it in an appropriate enclosure to avoid anyone touching the live wires, and add a fuse on the primary. 40W on 230V is 170mA so let's say a 0.5AT fuse (T meaning time delayed fuse so it survives the transformer inrush current).

There's a schematic in your manual:

[image]

The first thing in the device is a rectifier bridge, which means it will probably work on 24V DC too. In fact since the internal voltage seems to be 3V3 it will probably work with lower DC voltage too. So if you have an old 19V laptop brick you can always try...

I have no idea what the "PS GND" means, though, and the manual doesn't give useful info about it. Maybe Earth.

Comment: I considered buying 24V DC power supply, but since manual says - AC then I better stick to manual. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -3):

AC transformers usually come with products , it would be very unusual to see one for sale on it's own , to reduce your AC voltage down to 24VAC you could use a motor speed voltage regulator , with this you can adjust your AC voltage from O to 24OV , they cost about 18 pounds , there are cheaper types but they will not go below 5OV , they look like a dimmer switch surrounded by a heat sink , you will need to place it in an enclosure so that no one can adjust it after it has been set , an aluminium project box would be perfect , make sure to earth the box.

Transients or voltage spikes are a concern , it's important to protect sensitive equipment from them , the minimum protection I would use would be a type 2 surge protection device , a type 2 and a type 3 would be better , but these will provide protection from transients only , not a direct lightning strike , for this you would need a type 1.

Coils are a protection against spikes or transients , there are coils inside transformers and inverters , if you were to install a 12 or 24V transformer         inside your consumer unit and connect this to a pure sine wave inverter , you       could power the motor speed voltage regulator from the inverter , this would give       you 2 extra levels of protections against transients , spikes like a clear path        so they destroy equipment , coils are anything but a clear path and can absorb       transients.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Rory, but this is very poor advice. A phase-controlled mains power supply is definitely not suitable for a camera power supply, would destroy it and pose an electric shock hazard due to the non-isolation from mains. While the RMS voltage from a phase-controller can be adjusted the peak voltage could be as high as \$\sqrt\$ 2 times the mains voltage. Tip: capital 'O' is not the same as zero '0'. They are distinguished by their width and are not interchangeable.